# Custom Windows Service does not respond properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I've been tasked to fix a service that detects files created within a different partition of the server. This partition has a folder that is shared publicly to allow other accounts to access its contents.
I tested the process using the account that created the service and it works properly, being able to stop at breakpoints on debug mode. However, when another account transfers files within this said folder, it does not call the program, and debug mode does not work.
Can someone please explain this inconsistency?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I just discovered that the files uploaded by FileZilla is not triggering the windows service as opposed to copy/pasting files on the network path through windows explorer.

Can someone explain please. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not all file 'creation' events fire in FSW as one might imagine. If the file is locally created in another folder (temp?) and then moved to watched folder on the same drive it will fire only `renamed` and `changed` events.

Comment: so what do i have to do? implement the renamed and changed events as well?

Comment: In essence yes, you have to track more than one event. Moving a single file into watched folder will raise several changed and one created or renamed (depending on the manner in which it arrived). Keep in mind that renaming a file inside the same watched folder will trigger your event as well, you have to exclude that as a signal of a new file.

Comment: hmm, ok. i just added events for these two, invoking the created file function. i'm still coordinating with the testers. thanks much. :)